# Hacked iCloud account: how can I protect my iPhone security?

Tags: account-security, iphone, smartphone

My iCloud account has been hacked.

I access links sent by hackers that compromise my iCloud account. The hackers don't have physically access to my phone, the compromised links are sent by them through a picture via whatsapp, notification on pinterest or SMS including a link to a promotion.

Once I click on the respective compromised link, any application that I download from the App store is duplicated on another Android device, hence each time I am logging on Yahoo Mail, LinkedIN etc apps, I see that in the same time another Android device is connecting as well to my accounts- this device is named "iPhone", but it has Android logo. Then, I create a brand new iCloud account and this duplication doesn't take place anymore, until I click again on another compromised link.

How can I solve this security problem? I have to add that the compromised links are sent in different forms, as mentioned above, hence I stopped to use my social apps.

[image]